# VS 2017 WebApi Project cannot add reference

Tags: asp.net-web-api, visual-studio-2017

I created a new project in Visual Studio 2017 using the "ASP.NET Core Web Application" template.
Then i selected Web API template.
I installed Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer from Package Manager.
I don't know how add reference to this DLL in order to use DBContext (see image)

[WebApi Project Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tHFjb.jpg)

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer package contains SQL Server provider. In addition to that you need to add package

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore

which contains DbContext type.